# Meaning of "Läuft der Hase?"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm guessing it means something along the lines of "How's it going?"

Does it have a more specific query? What does the question imply?

Context: One of my friends asked me this after we caught up after a long time.
Complete Question: Wie geht's? Läuft der Hase?

I've encountered similar phrases when I searched on the internet but nothing specifically for this expression.

Comment: I guess, you are addressing *Jemand weiß, wie der Hase läuft*, meaning knowledge of a typical sequence of actions and causes. I'm not aware of any similar fixed phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered this expression several times among young adults in the south-west of Germany. In my experience, it is simply meant as a slightly humorous, light-hearted greeting among friends, basically asking "Is everything well?", "Is life going according to your plans?".

It might originally stem from other phrases as Hubert Schölnast and IQV suspect, but I don't think the speakers I've met consciously intended to reference those.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, we do not know, how the friend comes to this expression. I think it is not a common phrase which can be heard often.

I assume, his question is a mix of two better known expressions:

First there is the expression

> "Wissen, wie der Hase läuft" or "So läuft der Hase"

This means that someone knows how something works, knows about the thing, is well-versed. An English equivalent to this expression is "to know which way the wind blows".

The second expression is

> Läuft bei dir?

which is an expression of the actual youth language. Actually "Läuft bei dir!" is a congratulation when something is successful. So the question "Läuft bei dir?" is used to ask if all goes smoothly.

So I guess the friend mixed this two expressions together and the meaning is something like

> How are things going?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a common or well known phrase. Maybe it is a phrase that is used in a certain peer group (as part of the culture of this social group).

I just can guess the same as you. Obviously your friend did mean:

> Wie geht es dir?
>   How are you?

This it the literal translation of the phrase you heard:

> Läuft der Hase?
>   Is the rabbit running?

But I think the phrase was meant as an ellipsis (i.e. an incomplete sentence). In this case the full sentence would be:

> Wie läuft der Hase?
>   How is the rabbit running?

---

There is a similar phrase in German. Guidot is referring to it in [his comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46536/meaning-of-l%C3%A4uft-der-hase#comment112531_46536). This phrase is:

> wissen, wie der Hase läuft

The literal translation is

> to know how the rabbit is running

The corresponding English phrases are:

> to know how the land lies
>   to know how the wind blows
>   to know how things are going on
>   to be around long enough
>   to be experienced

I think, that your friend had this phrase in mind when he asked you, but what he really wanted to know was just

> How are you?